# Windows 10 Install Loop at Windows Logo (After Formatting harddrive)

Tags: windows, installation

not sure if im in right place now but i was told to re-post my origonal thread in the SuperUser

So.

I ran into a problem with my password not being rekognised after a windows Update (known issue - No solution)

So i tried to install windows 10 to remidy the problem.

All went well until i got to installing windows. I (maybe accidently) Deleted all the partitions (as told to do so online), then when i continued the install. i got the following problem.

As soon as i got the the Windows Logo (without spinning dots)it will just reset itself and start the process again, and asking me which version 64bit or 32bit of windows to install (so its getting onto the usb) Also sometimes it will not reset and will just hang on the window logo forever.

If i only try to boot off the Harddrive i get a blue screen with the following error 0xc0000098 - The Boot Configuration Data File dosent contain Valid info for operating system

I checked online for answers and went through everything i could find... Changing Boot drive to USB ect ect.

All provided no solution.

all im left with (after another Hard formatting of the Harddrive) is to try and install a New bios. (maybe that will help)

Im getting the feeling that the Harddrive being formatted does not have a Boot manager on it and maybe this is why it wont just Install windows correctly (maybe not i dunno)

But at the moment im at a loss. i really have tried everything thats is awarded me online from changing Boot sequences ect to Lagacy boot and back ect, but nothing has worked... I tried a new USB stick and a new Install of windows, still same problem.

My next hope is a new harddrive, but after reading other simlar issues i find they have been through all this too and returned to the same problems..

Im not sure what to do ...

My next move is to try a DVD ISO attempt, maybe a lower version of windows. or mabe link my Laptop harddrive upto my PC and see if i can install windows that way. Not sure how it will respond once put back into laptop though. maybe it will re-configure itself once back in laptop. not sure.

But , im sure others have been in this same situation.

If you have or know a way around this issue,please do enlighten me as i am at my witts end here.

thanks..

About ready to just buy a new laptop if no solution is found soon.

thanks guys

Comment: The disk is not the culprit, Windows can be installed to completely empty disks (how would you install it on a brand new one otherwise?). Are you booting in BIOS mode or UEFI mode? How have you prepared the installation USB?

Comment: Yes prepared the USB (how do you mean) - i formatted it and installed the windows media creation tool onto it.. then plugged it into the Laptop... I tried lagacy with USB 1st / Harddrive 2nd as boot sequence.. i have also been through UEFI and no matter what root i take or what USB i use. i get the same results... im at a loss.

Comment: Not sure what you mean now with BIOS mode or UEFI.. i F2 into BIOS to change boot sequence or Legacy/UEFI.

Comment: Maybe try installing Windows 7 and then upgrading to Windows 10 by mounting the ISO and running the setup.exe.

Answer (score 0):

> Im getting the feeling that the Harddrive being formatted does not have a Boot manager on it and maybe this is why it wont just Install windows correctly (maybe not i dunno)

The lack of a boot manager won't stop the Windows setup from writing files to disk during setup but it definitely will stop you from booting.

It sounds like you're okay at this point with nuke'ing the drive's contents and starting over. Since you know how to build bootable USBs, I suggest you make one for the open-source hard drive partitioning software Gparted https://gparted.org/livecd.php
Boot this up and use it to inspect your partition configuration.

Straight to the point of what you're after, use Gparted to delete all partitions on the drive, then restart your Windows setup and let it complete - Windows will see this as a brand-new drive and apply a bootmanager to it as part of setup.

If you want to do more precise surgery on just the lack of a working bootmanager aspect, and not erase the drive, use your Windows setup USB and while powering up press F11 repeatedly - this will take you to a boot menu, choose "Startup Repair"

Hope that helps :)

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/116478/discussion-on-answer-by-agent-smith-windows-10-install-loop-at-windows-logo-aft).